# Angular 5 - navigate to the same route with different parameter,

Tags: angular

Im trying to navigate to same route with different params, but its redirect me to to my ' ' route. When i'm pressing the back button its showing me the right page. any help....

My routes:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
  // .......
  {
    path: 'projects',    
    component: ProjectsComponent, 
    canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ], 
    children: [
      { path: 'details/:id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

My navigation option

```js
this.router.navigate(['/projects/details/',project.projectId ]);
```

At ProjectDetails i got :

```js
this.route.params.subscribe((params:any) => {
  this.currentProjectId = params['id'];
  this.getProject();
});
```

Comment: try this: { path: '', component: IndexComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.router.navigate(['projects', 'details' ,project.projectId ]);
```

If this still redirects you, then there is a navigate around ProjectDetailsComponent's `ngOnInit`,

or, maybe your route guard `AuthGuardService` `canActivate` is not fulfilled at the time of the routing event. (debug the canActivate)

Comment: i tried this but no luck....and i tried to to run it with out AuthGuardService, still have the same issue

Comment: Can we see the  AuthGuardService ?

Comment: Thanks @ForestG...it was my mistake, i had  href="" element and he made the redirection....such a noob :)